# if string exist in column check adjacent cell, writing loop, concise code, subset dataframe

Tags: r

I have a relatively large data sets and I want to test if each sting exist in a series of subset dataframes that were created from a larger data set.
I am able to accomplish this in three steps but but I would like to write a piece of code that does it in one step.

Because of the size of my files I would like to 
create sub-file t2.a use is to add a 1 or 0 in my file t1, remove it;
then repeat the process for t2.b, t2.c ...

My actual data sets resemble the dataframes below.

```
t1 <- data.frame(A1 = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "brown"),
                 A2 = c("orange", "purple", "yellow", "black", NA),
                 A3 = c(1,2,4,5,7))

t2 <- data.frame(B2 = c("black", "pink", "lime", "green", "grey", "mist", "blond", "grass", "violet", "red"),
                 B3 = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "d", "d", "a" , "c", "a", "b"))

> t1
      A1     A2 A3
1    red orange  1
2   blue purple  2
3  green yellow  4
4 yellow  black  5
5  brown   <NA>  7

> t2
       B2 B3
1   black  a
2    pink  b
3    lime  a
4   green  c
5    grey  d
6    mist  d
7   blond  a
8   grass  c
9  violet  a
10    red  b
```

My existing code is three steps:

```
# step 1. creates a subset of files 
for(i in unique(t2$B3)) {
    colName <- paste("t2", i, sep = ".")
    assign(colName, t2[t2$B3 == i, ])    
}

# step2. find if string exist in a given subfile
t1$t2.a <- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.a$B2 | t1$A2 %in% t2.a$B2, 1, 0)
#
t1$t2.b <- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.b$B2 | t1$A2 %in% t2.b$B2, 1, 0)
#
t1$t2.c <- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.c$B2 | t1$A2 %in% t2.c$B2, 1, 0)
#
t1$t2.d <- ifelse(t1$A1 %in% t2.d$B2 | t1$A2 %in% t2.d$B2, 1, 0)

# 3.remove each newly created data set 
rm(t2.a)
rm(t2.b)
rm(t2.c)
rm(t2.d)
```

The result should look like the dataframe below:

```
      A1     A2 A3 t2.a t2.b t2.c t2.d
1    red orange  1    0    1    0    0
2   blue purple  2    0    0    0    0
3  green yellow  4    0    0    1    0
4 yellow  black  5    1    0    0    0
5  brown   <NA>  7    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Essentially that's a wide form of `merge(t1, t2, by.x = 'A1', by.y = 'B2', all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2):

The following achieves the outcome you want.

Instead of repeating the same chunk of code several times, changing the arguments, we take advantage of R's `lapply`.

It's actually several steps inside of `lapply`, but it's a single call.

```
cbind(t1,
      do.call(what = cbind,
              args = lapply(unique(t2$B3), function(var_x){
                colName <- paste("t2", var_x, sep = ".")
                df <- assign(colName, t2[t2$B3 == var_x, ])
                df_2 <- data.frame(ifelse(t1$A1 %in% df$B2|t1$A2 %in% df$B2, 1, 0))
                colnames(df_2) <- paste("t2", as.character(var_x), sep = ".")
                df_2})
      )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of ways to do this, but you need a [left] join, followed by spreading to wide form. An option:

```
t3 <- merge(t1, t2, by.x = 'A1', by.y = 'B2', all.x = TRUE)    # add matching values of B3
t3 <- merge(t1, xtabs(rep(1, nrow(t3)) ~ A1 + B3, t3))    # spread B3 with xtabs, rejoin

t3 <- tidyr::spread(t3, B3, Freq)    # for the life of me I can't figure out stats::reshape

t3
##       A1     A2 A3 a b c d
## 1   blue purple  2 0 0 0 0
## 2  brown   <NA>  7 0 0 0 0
## 3  green yellow  4 0 0 1 0
## 4    red orange  1 0 1 0 0
## 5 yellow  black  5 0 0 0 0
```

Alternately, you can use `cbind` instead of the second join and spread if you use `as.data.frame.matrix` to explicitly convert the `xtabs` table to a data.frame:

```
t3 <- merge(t1, t2, by.x = 'A1', by.y = 'B2', all.x = TRUE)
t3 <- cbind(t1, as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(rep(1, nrow(t1)) ~ A1 + B3, t3)))
```

which returns the same thing with some extra rownames.

Comment: This does the reshape after the second merge, though the names of rows and variables might not be optimal `reshape(t3, direction="wide", timevar="B3", idvar=c("A1", "A2", "A3"))`.

Comment: \*\*applause\*\* Now that I see it, I was getting close before I gave up.

Comment: Nearly impossible to get it to work the first three tries.